# Can an alt attribute be set using CSS?

Tags: html, css, alt

I'm setting an image using a `<div>` tag like this:

```
<div id="logo"></div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
    #logo {
      background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat center;
      width: 180px;
      height: 82px;
      float: right; 
      padding: 15px 15px 0 10px;
      position: relative;
    }
```

How do I set an alt="" attribute for the image?

thanks!

Comment: You can't do it with CSS. CSS does not modify the markup of the document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is impossible to set an `<img alt="">` with `css`. But this can be done with `JavaScript` Example

```
<div class="logo><img src="../image.png"></div>

document.getElementByTagName('img').alt = "Anything";
```

Comment: Well, if the OP can change the HTML anyway, there's no need for JavaScript, since they would be able to type `alt="Anything"` in the markup!

Comment: Not that I disagree with this solution, mind you. If the image is important enough to warrant an alt attribute, it should be an `<img>` element rather than a `<div>` with a CSS background.

Answer (score 3):

That's not an image in the HTML sense - which is the only type of image an `alt` attribute (not tag) can be applied to.

You can't apply attributes of any kind via CSS - it's for styling, not applying mark-up.